# Problem with SSL certificate after buying a domain

Tags: dns, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

I hosted my website in 000webhost and bought a domain name for my website in Hostinger. After that, I started having issues do access my new website address. I receive the error message “NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID” saying that my connection is not private. I know that there is something to do with the SSL certificate but I do not know how to solve it.

Best wishes,

Jess

Comment: Sounds like a question for sister site ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0):

You can buy ssl certificate from godaddy, but i think you won't spend much money, if I'm right I can suggest you to try free ssl certificate from that website https://www.sslforfree.com/ I used it for 3 month just for educational purpose and it works. Just follow this website giudelines and you will install it in 15 minutes. But after that you have to change links on your website from http to https

Comment: I chose the manual option from sslforfree but I am not able conclude the 5th step because it says my the page does not exist. Should I create .well-known folder inside a specific folder?
5 - Verify successful upload by visiting the following links in your browser 
http://www.myblog.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/NXcdU2g2Y6X4nFEk449IFbOLvRbgNrEQy0VZoFqy2v0
http://myblog.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/bsocpvtNSXqoQlCML3I3_b0W2FqFE13YyUdowkW5t1I